Expected first writable signer key to be the fee payer - Solana MultiSwap Jupiter
Hello everyone hope all are good today ?
After many hours of working and seaching i'm forced to ask some help ...
I'm trying to do a multiswap on Jupiter with 2 quotes but i get error when sending swap the message return :
Expected first writable signer key to be the fee payer
When trying :
const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(3onho4yEyC00000000000000000000000DCwxk'))

const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
        payerKey: keypair.publicKey,
        recentBlockhash: blockhash,
        instructions: [
          ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({
            units: 3000000, // Set a higher limit, adjust as needed
          }),
          ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
            microLamports: 1,
          }),
          ...inQuote.setupInstructions.map(deserializeInstruction),
          deserializeInstruction(inQuote.swapInstruction),
          deserializeInstruction(outQuote.swapInstruction),
          deserializeInstruction(outQuote.cleanupInstruction)
        ],
      }).compileToV0Message(addressLookupTableAccounts);

I don't understand how to fix this issue if some can help me please
